# Exporting from Postgres and importing in Neo4j - some data lost in the process

Tags: neo4j

I have a Postgres table which I am exporting entirely to CSV. 
I am importing the CSV files, all rows, in Neo4j.
The counts of records are different between the export and import.
I am not getting any error during the export or the import.
Here are the counts. I am loosing 133 records.

```
select count(1) from wokas;
  count   
----------
 19798966
(1 row)

match (n:Woka) return count(n);
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 19798833 |
+----------+
1 row
16944 ms
```

The export command is:

```
COPY (SELECT woka_id, author_id, publisher_id, language_id, woka_title FROM wokas) TO '/Users/levi/woka-data/wokas.csv' WITH CSV header;
```

And the import command is:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/levi/woka-data/wokas.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Woka {woka_id: row.woka_id, author_id: row.author_id, publisher_id: row.publisher_id, language_id: row.language_id, woka_title: row.woka_title});
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure out which 133 records you are missing? Is there anything peculiar about them? Do you have a uniqueness constraint in neo on your unique key?

Comment: I have no unique constraints, no indexes, nothing, the db is empty.

Comment: Is nothing there before the load, this is the first load. Hard to figure out which 133 records are missing the total is almost 20 millions records. I was hoping maybe is a way to get a log of the load or to get a discarded records file.

Comment: I attempted another load this this time another node type with 4.1 million records. This time I got 4 records not loaded. Again the attempt was done using an empty db. I deleted the entire content of the folder "data", stopped the server and restarted before trying the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be something in your CSV, eg. stray quotes or null characters etc.

You can use a tool like csvkit to analyze your CSV.

You can also use Cypher to do some of that. Starting with:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/levi/woka-data/wokas.csv" AS row
RETURN count(*)
```

And then working your way from there ...

We covered some of that here:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_csv_data_quality

Comment: This RETURN count(*) returns exactly the same number resulted after import, which means that something may not be ok for all the records in the file or at least for 133 records something is not right there.